# Enable speedbar in ".el.gz" files?

Tags: speedbar, imenu

When I navigate through `describe-function' to the source of a function, very often the buffer is visiting a file with a ".el.gz" extension.

Often these files are multi-thousand lines, so a list of functions and variables would be quite useful.  And speedbar-mode provides exactly the sort of listing that I'm thinking about.

However, speedbar-mode doesn't work in these buffers.  Is there an easy way to get speedbar-mode to work in these buffers?

Comment: Speedbar uses the `imenu` library to generate the type of view you are thinking about.  The easiest way to handle your issue would be to build Emacs using the `--without-compress-install` flag ("*don't compress some files (.el, .info, etc.) when installing. Equivalent to: make GZIP_PROG= install*"); or, use an extraction utility and extract all of the `.el` files in the `lisp` and `emacs-lisp` directories.

Comment: ... recursively, that is ... (relating to the extraction comment above); i.e., extracting files in the subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that speedbar has variable containing a whitelist of file extensions which it will index.  This is `speedbar-supported-extension-expressions`.

The correct way to update this variable is:

```
(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".el.gz")
```

(Note that when I was working on this, I had to restart emacs before the .el.gz files were indexable by speedbar.)